# Python GUI cannot see global variable

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, python-3.x, global-variables

I am running a function. Once it is run I want to be able to re-use the `target_dir` variable which resides in the function's module (to be used by another function) so i am setting the variable to `global`.

However when i type in the Python GUI that variable's name: `target_dir` i get this message:

`NameError: name 'target_dir' is not defined`

Here is the module:

```
def SECdownload(year, month):
    import os
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    root = None
    feedFile = None
    feedData = None
    good_read = False
    itemIndex = 0
    edgarFilingsFeed = 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-' + str(year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2) + '.xml'
    print(edgarFilingsFeed)
    #print( edgarFilingsFeed ) #from the slides
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) )
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) )
    global target_dir
    target_dir = "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) + '/'
    try:
        feedFile = urlopen( edgarFilingsFeed ) # urlopen will not work (python 3) needs from urllib.request import urlopen
        try:
            feedData = feedFile.read()
            good_read = True
        finally:
            feedFile.close()
    except HTTPError as e:
        print( "HTTP Error:", e.code )
```

P.S. I have also tried this idendation as well:

```
 if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) )
global target_dir
    target_dir = "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) + '/'
```

Any ideas on how to make the variable `target_dir` usable after i run the `SECdownload` function?

Comment: Have you initialized the global target_dir (outside of the scope of your function)?

Comment: Would you please tell me what do you mean? i probably didn't :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return it. Just add at the end of your function

```
def SECdownload(year, month):
    import os
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    root = None
    feedFile = None
    feedData = None
    good_read = False
    itemIndex = 0
    edgarFilingsFeed = 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-' + str(year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2) + '.xml'
    print(edgarFilingsFeed)
    #print( edgarFilingsFeed ) #from the slides
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) )
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) )
    target_dir = "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) + '/'
    try:
        feedFile = urlopen( edgarFilingsFeed ) # urlopen will not work (python 3) needs from urllib.request import urlopen
        try:
            feedData = feedFile.read()
            good_read = True
        finally:
            feedFile.close()
    except HTTPError as e:
        print( "HTTP Error:", e.code )
    return target_dir
```

And then, when you can it, it will return target_dir.

```
target_dir = SECdownload(someYear, someMonth)
```

If you want to use global, you need to initialize your variable before.

```
target_dir = None
def SECdownload(year, month):
    import os
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    root = None
    feedFile = None
    feedData = None
    good_read = False
    itemIndex = 0
    edgarFilingsFeed = 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-' + str(year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2) + '.xml'
    print(edgarFilingsFeed)
    #print( edgarFilingsFeed ) #from the slides
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) )
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) )
    global target_dir
    target_dir = "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) + '/'
    try:
        feedFile = urlopen( edgarFilingsFeed ) # urlopen will not work (python 3) needs from urllib.request import urlopen
        try:
            feedData = feedFile.read()
            good_read = True
        finally:
            feedFile.close()
    except HTTPError as e:
        print( "HTTP Error:", e.code )
```

You can import it like that.

```
import test #name of your file

test.SECdownload(2014, 5)
print(test.target_dir)
```

Comment: I've already tried that and i got: `SyntaxWarning: name 'target_dir' is assigned to before global declaration` when i try to import the module

Comment: when i try to import the module

Comment: +if i type `return` in the code the next lines of code will not be executed

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant  I've added import example, it works fine for me.

Comment: What version of python do you use?

Comment: If i put return `target_dir` it will exit in the line i will put the `replace` keyword and will not execute the next lines of code in the module

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant Did you write return as I wrote it now? If it won't work for you, can you provide me more codes of yours? I don't know why return should be problem if its placed correctly.

Comment: you are right if it is placed correctly return shouldn't pose any problem. I have put it in the end of the module. I have tested the first code block you have provided. and if i type target_dir nothing comes up. If i type `print(target_dir)` i get `None` ...probably because it is set to `None` outside the function

Comment: There is no global var in the first code block. It just returns target_dir. To get it, you need to `target_dir = SECdownload(someYear, someMonth)`

Comment: i think i am getting a grip on this if i use the **second** code block and i type `df.target_dir` it works.... i some minutes to test it though

Comment: Oh my god! all i need is to type in the `GUI` this: `df.target_dir` can you please include that in your answer in order to mark it as correct?

Comment: Glad that you made it work :) I've already included it, just look at the last code block ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try would be to initialize the target_dir to a default value, outside the scope of your function. That is:

```
target_dir = None
```

or

```
target_dir = /some/directory
def SECdownload(year, month):
...
```

Comment: when i try to do that i get an error upon module import: `SyntaxWarning: name 'target_dir' is assigned to before global declaration`

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen

global target_dir

def SECdownload(year, month):

root = None
feedFile = None
feedData = None
good_read = False
itemIndex = 0
edgarFilingsFeed = 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-' + str(year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2) + '.xml'
print(edgarFilingsFeed)
#print( edgarFilingsFeed ) #from the slides
if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) ):
    os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) )
if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) ):
    os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) )


target_dir = "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) + '/'
try:
    feedFile = urlopen( edgarFilingsFeed ) # urlopen will not work (python 3) needs from urllib.request import urlopen
    try:
        feedData = feedFile.read()
        good_read = True
    finally:
        feedFile.close()
except HTTPError as e:
    print( "HTTP Error:", e.code )
```

Comment: If i run the SECdownload function i will get the `target_dir` variable? where do i write `global target_dir` in the GUI?

Comment: Write it outside the scope of your method and always have your import statements like so